# How to see auto generated Primary Key of a model and to use it like FK in Django?

Tags: python, django

How I know that models in Django have by default auto incremented id, but I want to see it in Django Administration and to take this id in order to put it in other model like FK

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = #TO BE auto incremented PRIMARY KEY
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Wallet(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usd = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Comment: `models.ForeignKey` ? and you probably want `customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)` which will make the actual database field `customer_id` .... if your question is how does django generate `customer_id` in that senario you can look into the source for ForeignKey ... or maybe you are asking how to mark a field as a `constraint`? basically i dont understand what your question actually is ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley My question is to make One-to-one relationship between this 2 models, when I make in Wallet.model FK of Customer_id, In my code occur and error "no such column: project1_wallet.customer_id"

Comment: @Fors1t: you should `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [**`AutoField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield) with [**`primary_key=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key):

```
from django.conf import settings


class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Wallet(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usd = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

For `customer`, it will make a column named `customer_id` with a foreign key to the primary key to the `appname_customer` table.

In the `ModelAdmin` of the wallet, you can use the [**`raw_id_fields`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) to use this to specify the primary key(s):

```
class WalletAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    raw_id_fields = ('customer',)
```

Comment: `models.IntField(primary_key=True)` would do the same thing wouldnt it? imho its marginally more expresive  (+1 all the same :) )

Comment: @JoranBeasley: no this will not distribute values by the database. An `AutoField` will let the database distribute ids, and will let Django then fetch the last assigned one.